# What is the use of __IO & static keywords in C?

Tags: c, static, microcontroller, keyword, stm32

I was checking out some code written for STM32F microcontroller and I found these keywords used before initializing a variable. I would like to know what is the significance of using this "**__IO**" & "**static**" keywords?

The line of code was given like that:

```
static   __IO   uint32_t   sysTickCounter;
```

Comment: `__IO` is probably a macro that can be either `volatile` or nothing

Comment: `static`, well, it means that it's restricted to this scope (file or function) but global (not automatic variable)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you. But in the case of  "static", once  I used a static varible  in another  C file by including it. Then how can it became restricted when I was able to use it on another file? would you mind to explain that?

Comment: of course if you _include_ the C file (not recommended) then the variable is visible in the file you're including from

Comment: So, if I don't include it in another file, is there any chance of getting used by another c program? I mean why should I need that "static" keyword then? Would you mind to explain please?

Comment: you don't need `static` unless the variable is defined with the same name in some other file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you. I have understood. But I found another problem. Listen, I have two c file one is containing main method and another one is containing only an int variable a=10;                                                                                                            I had included the other one into the main function. When I was trying to call printf("value: %d",a); from main function, it showed an error. Thant means I can't use non-static variable from another file(main) even if I include it in main. So, What would you say? Can you please explain that?

Comment: We are not a personal tutoring service. Comments are not for extended discussion or asking/answering further questions. All your questions will be answered by a textbook. Please get one; don't try learning C from obscure online tutorials or youtube videos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### `__IO` / `volatile`

`__IO` is not a C keyword. `__IO` is a macro for `volatile` - defined in STM32 standard peripheral library header files. E.g., in `core_cm4.h` (might be in a `CMSIS` sub-folder), you will find

```
#define     __IO    volatile
```

(If you use `gcc`'s `-E` option to use only the pre-processor stage, you can see the macro's expansion.)

The `volatile` keyword, in turn, is often applied to a variable to prevent the compiler from 'optimizing it out'. This is useful in embedded systems - where a variable might be used within an interrupt - and compiler optimizations could cause problems.

Short example ...

```
int main(void) {
    int ms = 0;

    ms++;
    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the generated assembly (using `sdcc` compiler for PIC12f629 target). As you can see, the `ms` variable has been 'optimized out'.

```
_main:
; 2 exit points
_00113_DS_:
;   .line   18; "main.c"    while (1)
    GOTO    _00113_DS_
    RETURN
; exit point of _main
```

If, on the other hand, we declare the variable as `volatile` ...

```
volatile int ms = 0;
ms++;
// etc.
```

the relevant instructions are preserved:

```
_main:
; 2 exit points
;   .line   16; "main.c"    volatile int ms = 0;
    CLRF    _main_ms_1_5
    CLRF    (_main_ms_1_5 + 1)
;   .line   19; "main.c"    ms++;
    INCF    _main_ms_1_5,F
    BTFSC   STATUS,2
    INCF    (_main_ms_1_5 + 1),F
_00113_DS_:
;   .line   21; "main.c"    while (1)
    GOTO    _00113_DS_
    RETURN
; exit point of _main
```

#### `static`

The effect of the `static` keyword depends on the scope in which the variable is declared.

- *file scope* - the variable's scope is limited to the current compilation unit (usually a file plus its `#include`d header files).
- *block scope* (e.g. within a function) - The variable is preserved in memory for the duration of the program. (For a function, this means that the value of the variable is preserved between subsequent calls to the function.)

#### Notes

- As vlk pointed out in a comment, another important use of `volatile` is for accessing peripheral registers (although you would use a pointer in that case).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have got it completely. So whenever we define something like  #define something 1234, the something becomes a macro. Am I right? I had a confusion with it. Anyway, I have another request for you. Would you mind to explain bit more about this line, "This is useful in embedded systems - where a variable might be used within an interrupt - and compiler optimizations could cause problems" ?

Comment: good answer, but this is not only for interrupts, but main purpose is to define variables mapped at addresses where MCU has peripheral and system registers, such as GPIO, SYSTICK, RCC, ..... because access to these registers can not be optimized.

Comment: @Olaf Would you please explain that?

Comment: @naasif How checking the standard or at least a good C textbook?

Comment: @Olaf Yeah. I have understood. Look I have no books at this time. So If you explain me a little bit that would help me a lot.That's it. Thank you.

Comment: Fine, @naasif , I'll bite: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html And "I have no books at this time" - That's the problem. Get one.

Comment: @Olaf you do not know if it is wrong as you do not know the scope of the variable. If it was declared in automatic variables scope it is wrong, but if in the global one it is right, as the variable will be in the static storage. So at most : it might be wrong depending on the variable scope

Comment: David. It does not prevent any optimizations. The `volatile` only guarantees that the variable will read from its storage location every time it is used, and stored after every change.https://godbolt.org/g/hgv4hD

Comment: @PeterJ_01: … which makes the original statement wrong - as I wrote. (FTR there is no "automatic variable scope" (this would exclude `static` storage class variables as these are explicitly not automatic). You mean block/function scope.)

Comment: @Olaf: I have updated my answer. Nonetheless, I am curious if you can outline a plausible scenario where a `volatile` `sysTickCounter` variable - whose name clearly indicates it is be updated inside a SysTick IRQ handler - would _not_ be declared at file scope.

Comment: If it's only used in a function, why would one define it at file-scope? Re making it `volatile (although not using the macro, it's to accomodate non-standard legacy compilers which used their own keywords for peripheral hardware registers, i.e. `__IO` does not necessarily mapo to `volatile`): It is commonly used to keep the compiler from optimising out memory accesses during debugging, e.g. for a watchpoint.

Comment: First rule on SO: don't make assumptions about how code not shown looks like. Even for code shown it's way too often not the code OP aks about.

Comment: @vlk: Thanks for your input. I have updated my answer with notes.

Comment: `volatile` is *essential* for anything that's not under full control of the compiler. The compiler does not know if/when/that an ISR using a variable is ever executed and hence might not see the relevance of accessing its current value. Memory-mapped IO is outside of compiler's control too: Writing to an IO location will have an effect on the hardware even though the compiler thinks it doesn't matter because the value is never read back. Reading an IO location may yield different results each time although the software did not write to the location. That's why `volatile` is needed.