# what is the equivalent of __IO in rust?

Tags: c, rust, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

- with the given example from here: [What is the use of __IO & static keywords in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337059/what-is-the-use-of-io-static-keywords-in-c), I am working on converting some C files that are using microcontrollers to rust
- I would like to know the equivalent of this volatile type in rust
- i am aware of unsafe code in rust: is the __IO alternative an example of this?
- I'm using a STM32f4XX type HAL

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://docs.rs/volatile/latest/volatile/ It came from a web search on: `volatile rust`

Comment: Rust doesn't have `volatile` types. Instead, it has [volatile read/write pointer operations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.read_volatile.html). You must use those or some wrapper around them, as mentioned by Craig.

Comment: i think the write pointer ops is what i was looking for, thx @PitaJ :) will check that one out and see if it works for my use case :)

Comment: __IO is simply `volatile` in STM32 HAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the I/O qualifier macros are defined in [core_cm4.h](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h) (normally included indirectly via stm324xx.h) thus:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #define   __I     volatile             /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions */
#else
  #define   __I     volatile const       /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions */
#endif
#define     __O     volatile             /*!< Defines 'write only' permissions */
#define     __IO    volatile             /*!< Defines 'read / write' permissions */
```

as you can see they are simply aliases for standard C qualifiers and not themselves C keyword or even compiler extensions - they are part of the CMSIS.

I am no Rust expert, but it seems that there is no direct equivalent in Rust, in that you cannot simply qualify a variable to ensure all accesses are explicit, so *memory-mapped I/O* uses a different approach.  There is an [mmio](https://docs.rs/mmio/latest/mmio/) crate and [`read_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read_volatile.html)/[`write_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write_volatile.html) and also a [`Volatile`](https://docs.rs/volatile/0.2.6/volatile/struct.Volatile.html) wrapper, all of which may be relevant to this issue.

Comment: all the comments in the op was super helpful as well - thanks for the explanation wrt the c part of things :)